# How does it come about that Jehana acquires such Deryni hatred in Bremagne?

Tags: deryni-series

The strong anti-Deryni bias in Gwynedd, and particularly the church in Gwynedd, developed during the backlash after the restoration.

Jehana is from Bremagne.   The Laws of Ramos should not have had any effect there, nor should the other changes that were the outcome of the restoration.

How did Jehana acquire, from her convent schooling in Bremagne, such hatred and mistrust of Deryni?  What is the connection between the anti-Deryni developments in Gwynedd, and Bremagne?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [discussion](https://www.rhemuthcastle.com/index.php/topic,2952.0.html) with several fans on the Rhemuth Castle website describes several theories of the development of Deryni hatred in countries neighboring Gwynedd.  Perhaps, "After the Deryni backlash in Gwynedd, many of the surrounding Kingdoms and states downplayed their Deryniness."  Or, perhaps, "after Festil I seized Gwynedd and enacted some rather oppressive laws to protect his Deryni supporters, that there was a wave of departing objectors, at least among those with the resources to leave - such as nobles and clergymen" who were absorbed into, and influenced, the local church.

The only information we could find in the books themselves is in the *Codex Derynianus*:

> The Princess Jehane was educated at the Convent of Saint-Elie new
> Millefleurs; the Abbess of this establishment, one Mother Rohane, was
> a notorious Deryni-hater.

I did not find any entry in the Codex for Mother Rohane, so there does not seem to be any explanation in the existing books, about where this Abbess acquired her Deryni hatred.

One more hint is a comment, in Camber/Alister's thoughts shortly before Cinhil's death, implying that Gwynedd was not the first to experience this process (emphasis mine):

> Now the anti-Deryni factions were about to get their wish. Cinhil
> would die within the year, probably within the month, if Rhys’s
> estimates were correct, and young King Alroy would be ruled by his
> regents. The last of the Deryni loyal to the Crown would be ousted
> from their offices, their positions of influence, no matter that many
> of them had served Gwynedd and its present king well and with
> distinction. And then the ostracism would begin, and the persecutions,
> and finally the bloodshed. **It had happened before, in other lands**, in
> other times.

Comment: Some people are just hateful. When those people are in position of power, people who know that about them and want to curry favor with them would act hateful to ingratiate themselves to them. Pretend to hate the group to get a promotion. Do that enough times and you can't stop pretending else you lose the privileges. Pretend hate or hate in the depth of the heart, the victim of that hate gets to taste the same results. And there is only so long you can pretend to hate someone until you hate them for real. My answer would be: because person in charge was hateful, others followed suit.